# How to infer nested interface keys

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have an interface that looks like:

```js
interface A {
  a: {
    b: string;
    c: number;
  };
}
```

And I want to get the nested key type based on the root key, but it's not working:

```js
const f = <K extends keyof A>(k0: K, k1: keyof A[K]) => {
  const t1: "b" | "c" = k1;
};
```

with the following error:

```
Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type '"b" | "c"'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"b" | "c"'.
```

How can I solve this?

## Updated

I found that `keyof` breaks something:

```
interface A {
  a: {
    b: string;
    c: number;
  };
}

const f = <K extends keyof A>(k0: K, v1: A[K], k1: keyof A[K]) => {
  const t0: { b: string; c: number } = v1; // This compiles(!!)
  const t1: "b" | "c" = k1; // This fails.
};
```

Comment: Type inference appears to be working just fine. Your example is somewhat contrived because you only have a single property `a` on type `A`. Imagine, instead, you had a second or a third property on `A`. Is it still safe to assume that `k1` is of type `"b" | "c"`? No. It could be anything... that's kind-of the point of generics.

Comment: See [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALkxz1ICMiBnMKUAcwG4TTcEiQBXAWzOidIC+-PABMi2FnghUa9YZJjtuvKPORCsArFjABPAA4oA0hF2VkAXmQBrUwHsYaANoAiOC4C6TLAjshqyI5WADxGyBAAHpAgIua2ug5oAHwAFNYADERGADQ2AIxE8YmoTkYeAJSWSZjq2jApbi65LmQu5Vj1jc0QbR0NIk3ILj3tnQPNreVAA)

Comment: @spender Thanks for your comment. My point is, I'm wondering why it is inferred as `string | number | symbol`, which looks too broad to me. In your example, it still fails to infer `k1` inside the function: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALkxz1ICMiBnMKUAcwG4TTcEiQBXAWzOidIC+-PABMi2FnghUa9YZJjtuvKPORCsArFgQB7ENWQxkAXmQAeANLIIAD0ggRlZAGsIAT13HUAPgAULgAMRJYANK4AjERunt4A2pYAugCUpj6YyMzIegZgyLZEAERkhcgAPsiFCKUVhRA1lTClZi4RTFpAA

Comment: I assume that, because you're using generics, no attempt is made to infer. Remove generics from the mix and the inference falls into place... kind of: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALkxz1ICMiBnMKUAcwG4TTcEiQBXAWzOidIC+-PABMi2FnghUa9YZJjtuvKPORCsArFgQB7ENWQxkAXmQAKANYAGIpYgBPXcdQAaZJYCMdx87QBteycXAF0ASlMAPkxkZmQ9AzBkAA8iACIyNOQAH2Q0hCzctIhCvJgssy8mLSA)

Comment: It seems that there certainly exists situations in generics are inferred like [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLmQGcwpQBzAbh2QCNCSyQqsBfLLUSWRFAIUw0CyAEQwA9uJHVc9UbThRpbDjACuIBGGDiQyGAB4A0sggAPSCAAmRZAGsIAT3Ew0APgAUdgIyE+AbSMAXQBKQVwEXRJkM0IAcglxOIAfOIUoOOQAXntvanYgA).

Comment: And I found that `keyof` operator breaks something ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLkx12QCNCBnMKUAcwG5jcFCQBXAW1OkdwF9GfLFgQB7EFWQxkAXmQAeANLIIAD0ggAJhWQBrCAE9R01AD4AFLoAMhRQBpkANwCMhVAG1FAXQe7Xew2M0Ty8ASllTImZxSTAbTDJKajp6ZBZkdi5oZD5ZJ2deNJiwZDB-ACJScuQAH2RyhGq5P0FGIA))